# componentDidUpdate called twice every route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

In my application i have a `HomePage` component which has navlinks in it. the route for this component is `<Route to="/browse/:item" exact component={HomePage} />`. so the component has a navigation bar with NavLink links to "sub routes" of it. for example a NavLink that leads you to `/browse/featured` or 
`/browse/new` and i added to this component the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate()` to just `console.log("UPDATED HOMEPAGE")` and whenever i click a NavLink this happens:
[image]

i tried to use `shouldComponentUpdate` with the `nextProps` and `nextState` params to see if indeed the state or props are changed (something that will cause a re-render) but they stay the same.
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: 
the code is on github https://github.com/idanlo/spotify-test-frontend
components that have the problem that i have seen are `AlbumView` and `HomePage`

ANOTHER EDIT: 
[image: updates]
this is a `console.log()` of the two updates happening, each one displaying the props before and after the update. on the first update you can see that the url is different so the update is supposed to happen but on the second update nothing is different, everything is the same (in the state everything is the same too)

Comment: there's not enough code here to see what the problem could be. components updating could be any number of things (and some intentional)

Comment: my code is on github if you can check it out https://github.com/idanlo/spotify-test-frontend the problem is on the `HomePage` and `AlbumView` components. maybe on other components too, i haven't checked yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually there are multiple calls because of changes made to the state. Check other files to make sure that no actions that modify the state are initially called. Even though you check for differences for nextProps, the variable that changes might not be in props.

Comment: Yes but it happens to 2 of my components. Maybe even more. i haven't checked

Comment: So I just looked at your code on Github. On the AlbumView component lines 11-13, you directly change the state by setting `album` to `null`. This causes a single re-render, bringing you to the second componentDidUpdate run. In the HomePage component, you also set the state in lines 11-15. You don't need to worry too much about about the componentDidUpdate running twice in general though.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers

Comment: @Hunter690 yes i do set the state but it's the initial setting which only sets it when component mounts doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**I suspect that Navlink's internal implementation uses setState with an updater function which is the source of this duplicate log**

I found that when I update state with an updater function then componentDidUpdate gets fired twice!

However when I pass an object to setState - componentDidUpdate is fired only once.

**setState(updater[, callback])**

*example:*

```
incrementScore = () => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
    score: prevState.score + 1
  }));
};
```

**VS**

**setState(stateChange[, callback])**

*example:*

```
this.setState({quantity: 2})
```

I guess it's because

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

read about setState on [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)